# If you know the type you're returning, would you still use output arguments?

Tags: go

A lot of Go code uses the following pattern:

```
var foo Foo
err := db.LoadFooByID(id, &foo)
// use the loaded foo
```

This pattern has its merits, especially, when it comes to a type you don't know in advance (`interface{}`). However, if you already know the type, it any other language, you would use `LoadFooByID` like this:

```
foo, err := db.LoadFooByID(id)
// use the loaded foo
```

And yet, people still prefer the former pattern.

I know that the question is very subjective, but if you had to provide a generic case solution that you apply consistently across your code base (for known types), which one would you go for?

Answer (score 6):

In the first form that takes a pointer, that gives you the possibility to reuse an existing `Foo` variable, preventing you from generating "garbage". It doesn't matter for a single `Foo`, but if you're loading `Foo`s in a loop, it might make a difference: you may use a single `Foo` variable in all iterations.

If you have the first form, you can always create a helper function that provides the functionality of the second form:

```
func loadFooById(id int) (*Foo, error) {
    var foo Foo
    err := db.LoadFooByID(id, &foo)
    return &foo, err
}
```

If you have the second form, you can't "convert" it to the first: if the `LoadFooByID()` function is the one allocating a new `Foo`, you can't make it reuse an existing one.